Let $A, B$ closed in a compact group. If $A$ or $B$ is $G_{\delta}$ then $AB$ is $G_{\delta}$
Let $G$ compact group, $A, B \subset G$ closed in G. Prove if $A$ or $B$ is $G_{\delta}$ then $AB$ is $G_{\delta}$.
Since, $A$ and $B$ are closed in a compact group, both are compact then $AB$ is compact. Suppose $A$ is $G_{\delta}$, then $$AB=\bigcup_{b \in B}(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_{n})b \subset \bigcup_{b \in B} U_{n}b \text{ , for all } n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
Since $AB$ is compact then exist $b_1,b_2, \dots, b_{k(n)}$ such that $$AB \subset \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{i=1}^{k(n)}U_{n}b_{i}$$
But the other conjugation I don't have it, so what should I do?
